# fluentvalidation does not show error or update Modelstate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, fluentvalidation

This is my code I have setup with the latest fluent validation library.

```
public class ReleaseViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<ReleaseViewModel> 
{ 
   public ReleaseViewModelValidator() {
     RuleFor(r => r.Name).NotEmpty().Length(1, 30).WithMessage("Name must not be longer than 30 chars."); 
  } 
}

[FluentValidation.Attributes.Validator(typeof(ReleaseViewModel))]
 public class ReleaseViewModel { public int ReleaseId { get; set; }

[Remote("ReleaseExists", "Release", ErrorMessage = "This name already exists.")]
public string Name { get; set; } 
public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } }
```

**GlOBAL.ASAX:**

```
 FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();
```

**VIEW:**

```
 model ILMD.Web.Models.ReleaseViewModel @* Remote Validation*@ <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Release")) 
 {
 <p class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)</p> 
 <p class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)</p> 
 <p class="editor-field">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)</p> 
 }
```

---

All my unit tests for the `ReleaseViewModelValidator` show green light. Fine.

But less cool is that entering some live data like 31 chars or entering nothing I do not see any client side error message.

Do I still have to include something in my partial view? The `ModelState` is also not correct its always true.

Comment: Does your form element (HTML source) show the unobtrusive validation attributes being rendered (i.e. data-val-required)? Can you show the rendered output for the form element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
[FluentValidation.Attributes.Validator(typeof(ReleaseViewModelValidator))]
```

Because in the FluentValidation attributes validator you have specify the actual validator (`ReleaseViewModelValidator`) not the `ReleaseViewModel`